# PL SQL LOOP logic if else if

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have an error when I judgment statement

Error: PLS-00103: Symbol "ELSE"
        ( begin case declare end
          exit for goto if loop mod null pragma raise return select
          update while with 
            <<
          continue close current delete fetch lock insert open rollback
          savepoint set sql execute commit forall merge pipe purge
Line: 134

```
FETCH date_time into r_pernr,r_aedtm,r_tprog,r_nobeg,r_noend,r_sollz,r_pabeg,r_paend,r_pdunb;
 IF l_time_s < r_nobeg THEN 
   raise e_req_hour_error2; 
 ELSE IF l_time_e > r_noend THEN 
   raise e_req_hour_error3;
 ELSE IF l_time_e IS NULL AND l_time_s IS NULL THEN 
    l_time :=  r_sollz;
 ELSE IF l_time_s IS NOT NULL AND l_time_e IS NULL THEN 
   IF l_time_s >= r_nobeg AND l_time_s <= r_pabeg THEN  
     l_time := r_pabeg - l_time_s + ( r_noend - r_paend );
     ELSE IF l_time_s >= r_paend AND l_time_s <= r_noend THEN  
       l_time :=  r_noend - l_time_s;
     ELSE IF l_time_s > r_pabeg AND l_time_s < r_paend THEN  
       l_time := r_noend - r_paend;
     END IF;
 ELSE IF l_time_s IS NULL AND l_time_e IS NOT NULL THEN 

   IF l_time_e <= r_pabeg THEN 
     l_time := l_time_e - r_pabeg;
     ELSE IF  l_time_e <= r_noend AND l_time_e >= r_nobeg THEN 
     l_time := r_noend - r_paend;
     ELSE IF l_time_e >= r_paend AND l_time_e <= r_noend THEN 
       l_time := r_pabeg - r_nobeg + ( l_time_e - r_paend );
     END IF;
 ELSE IF l_time_s IS NOT NULL AND l_time_e IS NOT NULL THEN  
   IF l_time_s >= r_nobeg AND l_time_e <= r_pabeg THEN 
     l_time := l_time_e - l_time_s;
     ELSE IF l_time_s >= r_nobeg AND l_time_e >= r_pabeg AND l_time_e <= r_paend THEN 
     l_time := r_pabeg - l_time_s;
     ELSE IF l_time_s >= r_pabeg AND l_time_e <= r_noend THEN 
     l_time := l_time_e - r_paend; 
     ELSE IF l_time_s >= r_paend AND l_time_e <= r_noend THEN 
     l_time := l_time_e - l_time_s;         
   END IF;
   IF l_time = 0 THEN 
     raise e_req_hour_error4;
   END IF; 
  END IF;
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Syntax error is because in Oracle if else should be in the format as shown below.

```
IF condition1 THEN
   {...statements to execute when condition1 is TRUE...}

ELSIF condition2 THEN
   {...statements to execute when condition2 is TRUE...}

ELSE
   {...statements to execute when both condition1 and condition2 are FALSE...}

END IF;
```